# How to enable HTTPS for a website running on Azure VM with existing SLL .pem certificate

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, virtual-machines, https, http

I am running http://clinicianwiki.com, a non-profit website for clinicians to exchange clinical information.

The domain provider of the website is porkbun, which also provides SSL certificate that is downloadable in .pem format.

What are the step I need to take (on the VM and on Azure portal) so that I can use https instead of http (which gives security warning) on the website? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can either add your certificate into your itself VM Webserver such as [Nginx](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-ssl-certificate-nginx), [Apache](https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache/) and so on or you can create an [Azure Application Gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/application-gateway/create-ssl-portal) and then add your certificate to do a SSL-Offload, it means that certificate is installed into your Azure Application Gateway and you have your VM as backend server.

[image: ssl]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is probably to use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). Setting up in Azure is quite complicated and can be costly for a new website. Setting up in Apache2 manually is also quite complicated.

I am still not sure what is the use of the .pem certs provided by porbun, but at least this solution worked beautifully for me.